# Referrer Exclusion List Migration to GA4 account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am currently working on migrating from Google Universal Analytics (UA) to Google Analytics 4 (GA4) and need assistance with migrating the Referrer Exclusion List from UA to GA4. The manual migration of the list is not feasible due to its size (117 entries).

I am looking for an automated solution using the Google Analytics Management API or any other suitable technology. The objective is to programmatically add the excluded domains from UA to the referral exclusion list in GA4.Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!